# View Pager Title Strip to show one title Only

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to get view pager title strip to show just 1 single page title(instead on this and the next page title ). Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. get pagerTitleStripe (pagerTitleStripe=(PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);)
2. set alpha to 0 in secondary views (pagerTitleStripe.setNonPrimaryAlpha(0);)
3. y listo!